# Gzip breaks form submission

Tags: php, forms, post, gzip

I'm using Wordpress 3.8.1. I enabled gzip like this:

```
ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
```

It's the very first thing at the top of my header. Had no issues with this until I tried to submit a form.

### Form:

```
<form id="upload" method="post"> [...] </form>
```

I've omitted the action purposely since I will handle the POST data on the same page.

### Problem:

On form submission,Firefox couldn't load the page and gives the following error.

> The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because it uses an invalid or unsupported form of compression.

Removing the gzip code fixes the error. How can I fix this?

Comment: Does your browser support gzip? Do you send gzip encoding headers in the response?

Comment: According to the gzip testers I found through Google, my browser supports it and my site is sending it correctly. I had no issues with gzip (and I've used it on previous projects) until I had to submit this form.